# Why inheritance from a class with private constructor is disallowed

Tags: c#

I can't find the reason that why inheriting from a base class the a private parameterless constructor is not allowed in C#. Here's the simplest example:

```
public class Base
  {
   private Base()
   {
   }

  public string Name { get; set; }
 }

 public class Derived : Base
 {
  public Derived(string name)
  {  
    base.Name = name;
  }
 }
```

Compiler doesn't compile this code. Why is it so? The class is not sealed of course, and while the base class is meant not to be instantiated many times (as in Singleton), I think the derived class has every right to be instantiated with a parametered constructor many times.
Why inheritance is disallowed in this case?

Comment: It looks to me as from the outside the base class doesn't have a constructor, if they are in the same project I bet internal would work :)

Comment: As long as you inherit from a class, this class need to have an accessible constructor. But you have put only a private one so your Derived class won't be able to intentiate it's base class. Put your parameterless constructor as protected to allow your Derived class to use it.

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) which clearly explains what `private` means. I.e. the member is accessible only by the type in which it's declared. A derived class does not have access to _any_ `private` members of the base class, including the constructor. Note that this does not mean the `private` constructor can't be called (it could be called by a non-private constructor) nor does it mean the class can't be inherited (it can provide a non-private constructor as well).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you need a constructor to instantiate a class, and the constructor is held private by the class you want to derive. No one but the class itself is allowed access to it. For all it knows it doesn't exist! (You might want to use a private constructor for the Singleton pattern for example)

If you want to allow inheritance, but keep the constructor from called outside, you need the `protected` keyword.

Comment: protected allows calling inside a derived class though. inheritance with private constructors would be good for factory patterns where you must instantiate it with a method. It also allows us to ensure our pooling systems are used

Answer (score 0):

You can't access something from another class if the `private` modifier is used; even from a derived class.

Have a look at this: [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> **private**
>
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or
>   struct.

And because the `Base` constructor has to be called when an instance of `Derived` will be created you can't use `private` in your case. You should use `protected` instead.